# Writing documentation - open source solutions for displaying docs online?

Tags: actionscript-3, frameworks, documentation

I've been working on a framework in AS3 that I want to release, but first I obviously need to prepare some documentation for it.

I've noticed that quite a few sites have the **exact** same layout, functionality etc as Adobe Livedocs, which has let me to believe that there's something open source out there for creating online documentation.

Here's some examples:

1. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/
2. http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/index.html
3. http://www.fisixengine.com/api/

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for tools that I can use to prepare online documentation?

Ideally the system would be specifically suited for documentation in **ActionScript 3**. I don't have a requirement in terms of the documentation being automatically generated either - if there's something out there that looks/works nice I'm happy to manually create the documentation (provided it comes with tools for easily adding classes, arguments, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has a free tool called [ASDoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_1.html). It generates documentation which follows the official Adobe patter. Frankly, it isn't worth it though. The ASDoc tool is buggy and unreliable. If it has difficulty finding an import, if an import isn't used, a comment is not correctly formatted, or you have your source code spread out in any sort of unexpected way, it simply breaks.

My company has lost over 50 developer hours (a few people tried to get a couple of different projects to work and failed) in an attempt to get around these limitations and our solution? We used [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) (A JavaDoc compiler). Is it perfect? No. Is it comparable to ASDoc in output? Sort of, it isn't as neat, and it would be nice if it treated things a little differently, but it works to display the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take a look at ASDoc first (for obvious reasons) and if I have any troubles I'll look at NaturalDocs. I've commented everything in a way that I believe is best supported (eg FlashDevelop picks up on all of my @param etc).

Comment: @Marty in a lot of cases it works well enough, but if you have any corner cases it will leave you with a war wound or two.

Comment: It's a shame about the command line thing.. Never any good with stuff like that. Do you know a similar tool with an actual GUI?

Comment: No, but you might be able to find a JavaDoc tool that has a GUI -- ASDoc is almost JavaDoc compatible (which is why NaturalDocs worked at all)

Comment: If you use FlashDevelop, you can go to Tools -> Flash Tools -> Document Generator.